# Manage ACL with Zend Framework and Doctrine 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, acl, doctrine

Does anyone know how to deal with ACL and Doctrine 2 inside a Zend Framework 1.11.10 Project ?

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The ACLs are handled with [Zend_ACL()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html), and as you do not have to use Zend_Db or Zend_Table or whatever classes Zend Framework provides, Doctrine-Integration should be as intended by the doctrine-manual. [Here's](http://ruben.savanne.be/articles/integrating-zend-framework-and-doctrine) an article on how to do it with Doctrine - it should be easily adaptable to Doctrine2.

Comment: I've already integrated Zend Framework 1.11 with Doctrine2 following ralphschindler's NOLASnowball integration on Github : https://github.com/ralphschindler/NOLASnowball/commits/doctrine2-managed-crud.
Everything's working fine but I can't really understand how to deal with Zend_Acl and Doctrine2 ... I don't wanna manage an XML file for ACLs, that's for sure. So I'm wondering what kind of entity should I create, etc...

Comment: The ACLs do not have anything to do with the database itself (which is the persistence-layer), but should reside in the business logic (or in Zend Framework). They do not allow or disallow database activity, but handle actions on resources - this also may be a database operation, but not on the persistence, but in the business logic layer. The only connection is if you want to generate your ACLs from data in the database, which is shown in [this tutorial](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/02/18/zend_acl-part-3-creating-and-storing-dynamic-acls/).